# Portable efficient alternative to PDEP without using BMI2?

Tags: algorithm, assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, bmi

The documentation for the [parallel deposit instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#Parallel_bit_deposit_and_extract) (`PDEP`) in Intel's Bit Manipulation Instruction Set 2 (BMI2) describes the following serial implementation for the instruction (C-like pseudocode):

```c
U64 _pdep_u64(U64 val, U64 mask) {
  U64 res = 0;
  for (U64 bb = 1; mask; bb += bb) {
    if (val & bb)
      res |= mask & -mask;
    mask &= mask - 1;
  }
  return res;
}
```

[See also Intel's `pdep` insn ref manual entry](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PDEP.html).

This algorithm is O(n), where n is the number of set bits in `mask`, which obviously has a worst case of O(k) where k is the total number of bits in `mask`.

Is a more efficient worst case algorithm possible?

Is it possible to make a faster version that assumes that `val` has at most one bit set, ie either equals 0 or equals `1<<r` for some value of `r` from 0 to 63?

Comment: Henry Warren, "Hacker's Delight", 2nd ed., chapter 7-5 gives a parallel suffix algorithm for a general 32-bit *deposit* operation, and claims it requires around 160 instructions (the exact count will depend on the specifics of a processor's instruction set). If I understand your second question about the special case of a 1-bit deposit correctly, it boils down to quickly isolating the *r*-th 1-bit of `mask`.

Comment: For your special case of a 1-bit deposit, will `r` be known in advance, or do we have to first find `r` by examining `val`, before isolating the `r`-th 1-bit in `mask`?

Comment: r can trivially be found if it is not known already.  Assume it is known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as an additional note, since this came up for me again, I found [Sebastiano Vigna's method](https://vigna.di.unimi.it/ftp/papers/Broadword.pdf) for finding the nth set bit to be faster in practice. It contains no branches or conditional moves.

Note that `leq_bytes` and `gt_zero_bytes` might be implementable using SSE instructions, but this version the advantage of being completely portable.

```cpp
const uint64_t sMSBs8 = 0x8080808080808080ull;
const uint64_t sLSBs8 = 0x0101010101010101ull;
    
inline uint64_t
leq_bytes(uint64_t pX, uint64_t pY)
{
    return ((((pY | sMSBs8) - (pX & ~sMSBs8)) ^ pX ^ pY) & sMSBs8) >> 7;
}
    
    
inline uint64_t
gt_zero_bytes(uint64_t pX)
{
    return ((pX | ((pX | sMSBs8) - sLSBs8)) & sMSBs8) >> 7;
}
    
    
inline uint64_t find_nth_set_bit(uint64_t pWord, uint64_t pR)
{
    const uint64_t sOnesStep4  = 0x1111111111111111ull;
    const uint64_t sIncrStep8  = 0x8040201008040201ull;

    uint64_t byte_sums = pWord - ((pWord & 0xA*sOnesStep4) >> 1);
    byte_sums = (byte_sums & 3*sOnesStep4) + ((byte_sums >> 2) & 3*sOnesStep4);
    byte_sums = (byte_sums + (byte_sums >> 4)) & 0xF*sLSBs8;
    byte_sums *= sLSBs8;
    
    const uint64_t k_step_8 = pR * sLSBs8;
    const uint64_t place
        = (leq_bytes( byte_sums, k_step_8 ) * sLSBs8 >> 53) & ~0x7;
    const int byte_rank = pR - (((byte_sums << 8) >> place) & 0xFF);
    const uint64_t spread_bits = (pWord >> place & 0xFF) * sLSBs8 & sIncrStep8;
    const uint64_t bit_sums = gt_zero_bytes(spread_bits) * sLSBs8;
    const uint64_t byte_rank_step_8 = byte_rank * sLSBs8;
    return place + (leq_bytes( bit_sums, byte_rank_step_8 ) * sLSBs8 >> 56);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The second part of the question, about the special case of a 1-bit deposit, requires two steps. In the first step, we need to determine the bit index `r` of the single 1-bit in `val`, with a suitable response in case `val` is zero. This can easily be accomplished via the POSIX function `ffs`, or if `r` is known by other means, as alluded to by the asker in comments. In the second step we need to identify bit index `i` of the `r`-th 1-bit in `mask`, if it exists. We can then deposit the `r`-th bit of `val` at bit `i`.

One way of finding the index of the `r`-th 1-bit in `mask` is to tally the 1-bits using a classical [population count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) algorithm based on binary partitioning, and record all of the intermediate group-wise bit counts. We then perform a binary search on the recorded bit-count data to identify the position of the desired bit.

The following `C`-code demonstrates this using 64-bit data. Whether this is actually faster than the iterative method will very much depend on typical values of `mask` and `val`.

```c
#include <stdint.h>

/* Find the index of the n-th 1-bit in mask, n >= 0
   The index of the least significant bit is 0 
   Return -1 if there is no such bit
*/
int find_nth_set_bit (uint64_t mask, int n)
{
    int t, i = n, r = 0;
    const uint64_t m1 = 0x5555555555555555ULL; // even bits
    const uint64_t m2 = 0x3333333333333333ULL; // even 2-bit groups
    const uint64_t m4 = 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fULL; // even nibbles
    const uint64_t m8 = 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffULL; // even bytes
    uint64_t c1 = mask;
    uint64_t c2 = c1 - ((c1 >> 1) & m1);
    uint64_t c4 = ((c2 >> 2) & m2) + (c2 & m2);
    uint64_t c8 = ((c4 >> 4) + c4) & m4;
    uint64_t c16 = ((c8 >> 8) + c8) & m8;
    uint64_t c32 = (c16 >> 16) + c16;
    int c64 = (int)(((c32 >> 32) + c32) & 0x7f);
    t = (c32    ) & 0x3f; if (i >= t) { r += 32; i -= t; }
    t = (c16>> r) & 0x1f; if (i >= t) { r += 16; i -= t; }
    t = (c8 >> r) & 0x0f; if (i >= t) { r +=  8; i -= t; }
    t = (c4 >> r) & 0x07; if (i >= t) { r +=  4; i -= t; }
    t = (c2 >> r) & 0x03; if (i >= t) { r +=  2; i -= t; }
    t = (c1 >> r) & 0x01; if (i >= t) { r +=  1;         }
    if (n >= c64) r = -1;
    return r; 
}

/* val is either zero or has a single 1-bit.
   Return -1 if val is zero, otherwise the index of the 1-bit
   The index of the least significant bit is 0
*/
int find_bit_index (uint64_t val)
{
    return ffsll (val) - 1;
}

uint64_t deposit_single_bit (uint64_t val, uint64_t mask)
{
    uint64_t res = (uint64_t)0;
    int r = find_bit_index (val);
    if (r >= 0) {
        int i = find_nth_set_bit (mask, r);
        if (i >= 0) res = (uint64_t)1 << i;
    } 
    return res;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty cool.  There's a few magic numbers in `find_nth_set_bit`, however... so I'm not sure hot to extend it to an integer that is more than 32 bits... say 64, 128, or even 256 bits.

Comment: @markt1964 I have changed the code to a 64-bit implementation and have used named masks to make it clearer what these masks do.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is.

I just finished coding the following routine. There are multiple points of optimization, but it does the trick in O(lg^2 N) asymptotic time.

```cpp
    #include <cinttypes>

    uint64_t pdep64r (uint64_t src, uint64_t mask) {

        static const int W = 8*sizeof(uint64_t); // bits in word
        static const int LGW = 6; // log2(64)

        static const uint64_t UMASK[]= {0x0001, 0x0000000100000001, 0x0001000100010001, 0x0101010101010101,
                               0x1111111111111111, 0x5555555555555555};
        static const uint64_t XMASK[]= {0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFF, 0x0F, 0x03};
        static const uint64_t MXOR[] = {0x00000000FFFFFFFF, 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF,
                       0x00FF00FF00FF00FF, 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F,
                       0x3333333333333333, 0x5555555555555555};

        // recursive popcount every 2^k subblock of the mask and store the counts
        uint64_t pcmask[LGW+1]; {
            pcmask[LGW] = mask;
            for (int k=LGW; k>0; --k) {
                pcmask[k-1] = (pcmask[k] &  MXOR[k-1]) +
                             ((pcmask[k] & ~MXOR[k-1]) >> (1<<(LGW-k) ) );
            }
        }

        uint64_t dst = src;

        // solve by recursively splitting the problems into 2^k x 2^(N-k) blocks
        for (int k=0; k<LGW; ++k) {

            uint64_t pclo = pcmask[k+1] & MXOR[k]; // popcount of half

            const uint64_t UNIT = UMASK[k];
            const uint64_t EXT  = XMASK[k];

            uint64_t m = UNIT;
            for (int n=0; n<LGW-k; ++n) {
                uint64_t d = ( (pclo>>n) & UNIT)*EXT;  // select blocks with d0=1
                m = ( (m<<(1<<n)) & d ) | (m & ~d); // expand the mask m by a power of 2 if that digit is set
            }
            m -= UNIT;

            uint64_t l = dst &  m; // keep in lower half
            uint64_t h = dst & ~m; // must be shifted to upper half

            for (int n=0; n<LGW-k; ++n) {
                uint64_t d = ( (pclo>>n) & UNIT)*EXT;  // select blocks with d0=1
                h = ( (h>>(1<<n)) & d ) | (h & ~d); // shift <<(2^d) only for blocks with d set
            }
            h <<= (1<<(LGW-k-1));
            h &= ~MXOR[k]; // remove spillovers to next block

            dst = l | h;
        }

        // as we only introduced zeros by shifting left there may be leftover bits that need cancelling
        return dst & mask;
    }
```