# Isolating bits and flattening them

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

### Problem

Suppose I have a bit mask `mask` and an input `n`, such as

```
mask = 0x10f3 (0001 0000 1111 0011)
n    = 0xda4d (1101 1010 0100 1101)
```

I want to **1)** isolate the masked bits (remove bits from `n` not in `mask`)

```
masked_n = 0x10f3 & 0xda4d = 0x1041 (0001 0000 0100 0001)
```

and **2)** "flatten" them (get rid of the zero bits in `mask` and apply those same shifts to `masked_n`)?

```
flattened_mask = 0x007f (0000 0000 0111 1111)

bits to discard         (___1 ____ 0100 __01)
first shift             (  __ _1__ __01 0001)
second shift            (       __ _101 0001)
result         = 0x0051 (0000 0000 0101 0001)
```

### Tried solutions

**a)** For this case, one could craft an ad hoc series of bit shifts:

```
result = (n & 0b10) | (n & 0b11110000) >> 2 | (n & 0b1000000000000) >> 6
```

**b)** More generically, one could also iterate over each bit of `mask` and calculate `result` one bit at a time.

```
for (auto i = 0, pos = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    if (mask & (1<<i)) {
        if (n & (1<<i)) {
            result |= (1<<pos);
        }
        pos++;
    }
}
```

### Question

Is there a more efficient way of doing this generically, or at the very least, ad hoc but with a fixed number of operations regardless of bit placement?

Comment: This sounds nasty. What's the actual problem that you're trying to solve? There must be an easier way.

Comment: For predefined bit masks you could generate the shifts at compile time with some TMP.

Comment: I read it 5 times, still can't understand what flattened bit means. What is the truth table for this operation?

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm trying to decode operands embedded in opcodes, e.g. getting the values of `r` and `d` given the pattern `0000 11rd dddd rrrr`.

Comment: @SergeyA With the pattern `0000 11rd dddd rrrr` (where `r` and `d` are arbitrary bit values), applying a mask for `r` would give you `____ __r_ ____ rrrr`. I would like to then "flatten", or get rid of the useless bits (`_`) in between the remaining `r`s, leaving me with just a continuous number `000r rrrr`.

Comment: I am still not following. There are only 0 and 1 values in any given bitset, yet your example has 4 - 0, 1, r, and d. Can you please provide a real bitset example?

Comment: I'd go with an ad hoc approach. You'll typically need a small handful of shifts and masks; not a big deal. The broad generic case that I thought you were describing originally is still nasty, but, luckily, you don't have that.

Comment: NO, there's no neat way of doing it. You can build a fairly simple function to flatten a bitset for you, or hardcode lots of shits and masks.

Comment: @SergeyA -- he wants to gather the **values** from the `r` bits into a register index. So think of the `r` bits as being numbered: `r4`, `r3`, `r2`, `r1`, `r0`, from left to right in the pattern. Compute the value as if those bits were all contiguous: `r4r3r2r1r0`. It's a common hardware thing, where the bits for different things are interleaved and you have to pick out the bits for one of the things.

Comment: In most of the assembly languages I have encountered, there are no "useless" bits and the bits depend on their positions.  For example, if a register field is 101 (meaning register 5), you can't squish or flatten to 11 because 11 means register 3.  This also applies to bit patterns in hardware devices.

Comment: How many of the R masks do you need to check?

Comment: See also [Bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

Comment: The only reason I was looking to move away from ad hoc bit shifts was to be able to make a listing of opcodes and their operand positions, such that I could parse using the that instead of hard-coding each individual operand's decoding. The idea behind this is that I could go both ways, i.e. encode and decode, without needing to hard-code the bitshifts twice (1 to read, 1 to write). Should there be no neat way to do this, I will likely stick to implementation **b)** and only store the masks in the table (I could see creating two lambda's and storing those a la **a)** but that sounds ugly)

Comment: so you want to pack the selected bits? That's called [parallel bits deposit in x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#Parallel_bit_deposit_and_extract). [Portable efficient alternative to PDEP without using BMI2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38938911/995714), [Extracting bits with a single multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14547087/995714), [what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932240/995714)

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient generic approach would be to loop over the bits but only process the number of bits that are in the mask, removing the `if (mask & (1<<i))` test from your loop and looping only 7 times instead of 16 for your example mask. In each iteration of the loop [find the rightmost bit of the mask](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightMultLookup), test it with n, set the corresponding bit in the result and then remove it from the mask.

```
int mask = 0x10f3;
int n = 0xda4d;

int result = 0;
int m = mask, pos = 1;
while(m != 0)
{
    // find rightmost bit in m:
    int bit = m & -m;
    if (n & bit)
        result |= pos;
    pos <<= 1;
    m &= ~bit; // remove the rightmost bit from m
}
printf("%04x %04x %04x\n", mask, n, result);
```

Output:

```
10f3 da4d 0051
```

Or, perhaps less readably but without the `bit` temp variable:

```
if (n & -m & m)
    result |= pos;
pos <<= 1;
m &= m-1;
```

How does it work? First, consider why `m &= m-1` clears the rightmost (least significant) set bit. Your (non-zero) mask m is going to be made up of a certain number of bits, then a 1 in the least significant set place, then zero or more 0s:

e.g:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx1000
```

Subtracting 1 gives:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx0111
```

So all the bits higher than the least significant set bit will be unchanged (so ANDing them together leaves them unchanged), the least significant set bit changes from a 1 to a 0, and the less significant bits were all 0s beforehand so ANDing them with all 1s leaves them unchanged. Net result: least significant set bit is cleared and the rest of the word stays the same.

To understand why m & -m gives the least significant set bit, combine the above with the knowledge that in 2s complement, `-x = ~(x-1)`