# What's a fast way to space-out bits within a word?

Tags: performance, bitwise-operators

I have a 32-bit value in the lower part of a 64-bit register; the top part is 0's. Letting `X` denote a bit with information and with bits listed from LSB to MSB, here's what it looks like:

```
X X X  ...  X 0 0 0 0 ... 0
```

Now, I want to "space out" the bits with information, so that I have

```
X 0 X 0 X 0 ... X 0
```

(or if you'd rather put the 0's first, then

```
0 X 0 X 0 X 0 ... X
```

is fine too.)

What's a fast way to do that?

A multi-CPU-architecture-relevant answer would be nice, but something specific to Intel x86_64 and/or nVIDIA Pascal SM's would be the most relevant.

Comment: you said that "the top part is 0" but actually the bottom part is 0

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: I listed the bits from first to last, see edit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4597940/781723

Answer (score 5):

This is known as [Morton number](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableObvious), which is a specific case of *parallel expand* which is in turn the reverse of *compress right* in the following questions

- [What's the fastest way to pack 32 0/1 values into the bits of a single 32-bit variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26200961/995714)
- [Shift masked bits to the lsb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28282869/995714)

One general solution might be

```c
uint64_t bit_expand(uint64_t x)
{
    // Input:  00000000ABCDEFGH, each character is a nibble
    x = ((x & 0xFFFF0000) << 32) | ((x & 0x0000FFFF) << 16);
    // Result: ABCD0000EFGH0000
    x = (x & 0xFF000000FF000000) | ((x & 0x00FF000000FF0000) >> 8);
    // Result: AB00CD00EF00GH00
    x = (x & 0xF000F000F000F000) | ((x & 0x0F000F000F000F00) >> 4);
    // Result: A0B0C0D0E0F0G0H0. Each byte: abcd0000
    x = (x & 0xC0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0) | ((x & 0x3030303030303030) >> 2);
    // Result:                   Each byte: ab00cd00
    x = (x & 0x8888888888888888) | ((x & 0x4444444444444444) >> 1);
    // Result:                   Each byte: a0b0c0d0
    return x;
}
```

However the constant generation might be inefficient on RISC architectures because the 64-bit immediate can't be stored in a single instruction like on x86. Even on x86 [the output assembly is quite long](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIArKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFc8XaYDmlCBEzEBBk%2Bfly2mPZ5DDV1BAVhkdFxtrX1jVktCsM9wX3FA2UAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQmm24T%2BIIAdAhH2CYaAIK3d17BBABskgD6BPsRhB%2BYqgShnQEGegneX32qnm%2BwA9LD9hokcikXcLG4ACLYABiAHEABKPEwAdis932FKhh02GP2UFUhzMr0RqmxbOxKJhRzc3P2mzMXOJbjpEAZ5mZGlUKPZ2K5x15XFe8yOFkparhCLRmJROIJKMearFNLpYqZLLZKKRFstguF9MZEqlGmt0o5yLlN022H2AA5lZtVfD9mikdqNDikXqNAbKUbaaKHebkW7ncn3YchSLTY7U1a03mNB7rvtJP7A5qNBYNG4NBjw6ncRp8dHybHqfHsyya93q72ezXbVnE5LNhpR%2BOx5OJ0WvfsBSqYxS4ybh6ofeuN5ut36M3aE%2BKWZIj8eT6fS9TPd6uGXF/tiJgCCsGFCF/cSRiiW%2BzJssDQQvtsAADWUO5QgxSQICYGEoCgKDVx3bleXPEk90grkzUlZD5WOOcuViHlW3VIj1RQkU0NXAVqR5HDr13Mi4IPSVr3mZU33uNAGAmfYwQIH1IQCOQABUTFiCxFRE2kjkk0lbyAkCwIgxFFgA4DQPAiB9mvUgVPk9TcO0uS1MUzZFlk1SFI00sDPMvTYmUwyLP2JVrN0xTiVMwidKMjS/Rc7z9gATnsmyIK4Qs/IsrgtLM1yIC4AUIvUrgTMS0KrK8yK7KJYkPwDT8nheCFvl%2BAh/kBYEPgEwTQUKz5vmhbKyTuNV70fYhnygHiivmKqRIsfcvWLMwEIw1kJKo3lYiVOjOtqr4eqEvqBsvOdkNG7FxsQnDJD9W8SMzWbwTqhbhNE5ahsLVcNtiSTsOFSRLtIw63mO3qzqNFbFXQx1rtu6jhX5VjmuImaaqO%2Ba3v6j7i3i77zU2u7VsHZ7ush87Z19OHJV%2BiaaKVPa1SesGXohxb3ovYsSyxsabtx4VMdBrrXrJqGKYxx71oR/6KULV8HjfHL8qZyEFCBNYAHkvF4kqFGJvjiqBkkmrVJgpdQfYAFk7lxABJYUpJZH0NAeswNDCjQjZNs25ACAI%2BZVtXNbuIQAGkKQNyUja9i2fe9o2bbtvLPOF74ASBBh0B9GX232D4PgiZ5aEcBh44UAB3JgEneGCtd1twACoIjhrXXZnb13PtykQ/2UWmDWdBJYICxCAUGOw%2BBKOW/zzCwskLhVzuO5LXuIfLUrilWqfOla/rxvm4IVunpnzAG6l%2BfF8RsxS2pmVh%2BHvn3yFubvmXxv3hl4miqhRWZM8yf2unsXMEbzuF/R70t7lbmdqBkGZtPqWr9ZbQ1nF9OmfJ5yeX2naAB0sW7vwpAhRGX0CaUiXk/F%2BF8QHeiUuApSB9BZsTuBwRYtBOCxF4H4DgWhSCoE4DySw1ga7LFWJgRkmweCkAIJoEhiwADWIBTbnC4D6YaPpiRIi4AFWI0jjb6E4JIShPDaGcF4AoEAGguE8MWHAWAMBEAoFQCwBIdBojkEoGgYxpiYh1BYFFU2fA6AEGiOoiAERlG/GYMQAAnpwThli2CCHFgwWgvjqG8CwCwQwwBxDhNIPge8VQABumB1FxIBJUKW6xOEvDaMo2geAIjEDqN4jwWBlEEGIHgFg2i%2BAGGAAoAAangTAadxYJEYH43g/BBAiDEOwKQMhBCKBUOoOJuhNj6GiSgaw1h9CFPUZARYqAEgdDSQAWnFpsfY6yqApOIBEZImB1lMAUCwNRbRKgdBcBHUYzRSCBGmEUEo2RkipAEHc15uQ0i9GeXMVo7RqiTE%2BeMS5VQBBdHqL8/opQhjdBBXCqFTyYUSEWAoFhaw9CVMwNkkh8iOAUNIFQmhdCOB3AAEoa32MAZAyBNJcHOGYOkBSGBeGhHSBhVhLAGXwEQYg7CWj7A8FY%2Bg/KtgmV4Nw8JOikCWJMaK8xEA5XWJAMAexjik4uMoO4uJniSldNIAExgBBgmhOUZE6JsSaEJKuXgFJaSaEZOQFkg1uSyFxIKUUkpZT1g0MqdU2pVB6lNJaW0jpVDOE9OEKIcQgyo0jLUMo3Q8QDBGBmYw7lnrFkQGWastIGytk7L2dEQ5SgTlnIuYC5wEBXAguJA8iO0LZgxFeIkN5HQ61tu%2BfkZFzaQCtoqOCzowLPBNAkPWwdHRIVTEKCigdI7MjNAnZMJtLznLopWJilo2LcWkPIUouJpK1yvHWe8altL6WMo5bM7lAFeUkAFdpYV8rojsLspK2pEBZVGJfWQCgSqf0qoSAkZA7xgABQ1c44gridU0L1T4g1RqgkhLCdazAUSjBWoiXgRJjh7XKKdS67gvA3X5MKcUnxPqKlVJqdKupTAGnNNae0zpxGhnRv6RIaQ8alCJvGSAaQqbjA3psFm%2BAua1mcE2ds3Z%2BzS3HNOecgFtrq21tHWMBt6BV3/JyO89I6n7m6Y6Np2Fk6gXwoM3oMzEKV29peeMBdY6HPdBM6ipYm6BlcPvLu/FhLiW8FJUkNO0Qz13EEslc4Gg6Q0uQEFa9GabB3sIA%2BrYgrn3WPYaWD90r%2BEgHXOcCRZtpGyM2DIre%2BLFGkBqbETR/mVEcDUYIrRdHdEGOVQq/97WBh4FpSIyDWq3EeOCPqtjSGTUofNehy1vrsO4btakgjqhMnONdYIPJHryPeowDNrzAa6NBoYyG5j4aDVRr6bG7jsgE1jJoboMwUy02mAS/MiI2aJP5qk1sytKm/A1tuZZlojzZ19paEZtICKwc9uB/Z5TQ7p0Ius8Olzdn/kTAs4uqztnodzDRRizzO6ul7oJQeklnBj2nskPsHrdKRGRci/FrliXcDJbFd%2BNLgHRXsIFNlrQMrDEirMZ1jnAxiBJPeOs3Y0Tkpm369B7VQ2vFhP8UYwJ42zVxItZhnbNrkkLfSUt51K22OkY216yj23qN7d5/RxjoaWMRu6bIc7AzLvDN4zdnQeghPpsZy9t7tC80CALZsb7Q6bnuAB5p1zoP23g8j5Dhg0fYdTscxpxH06k9o5GJHrPM6Zj2dxx5rF3nCe%2BZJwFzg5KdZCDcOsxpd4xeSBpfsSXRhNKbDp/3CAnK5lJb5Y%2BoVwvWccPmDz3hpAECYCYFgGIOaKu8Gq7V5RpLGvbu0bl4kAVzg%2Bi4MSexAUAqWw0CmzgIeiXL9Uc13nROzDl/q2PlipB9kpGcJIIAA%3D). Here is another possible implementation as described on [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#InterleaveBMN)

```c
static const unsigned int B[] = {0x55555555, 0x33333333, 0x0F0F0F0F, 0x00FF00FF};
static const unsigned int S[] = {1, 2, 4, 8};

unsigned int x; // Interleave lower 16 bits of x and y, so the bits of x
unsigned int y; // are in the even positions and bits from y in the odd;
unsigned int z; // z gets the resulting 32-bit Morton Number.  
                // x and y must initially be less than 65536.

x = (x | (x << S[3])) & B[3];
x = (x | (x << S[2])) & B[2];
x = (x | (x << S[1])) & B[1];
x = (x | (x << S[0])) & B[0];

y = (y | (y << S[3])) & B[3];
y = (y | (y << S[2])) & B[2];
y = (y | (y << S[1])) & B[1];
y = (y | (y << S[0])) & B[0];

z = x | (y << 1);
```

A [lookup table](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableLookup) can also be used

```c
#define EXPAND4(a) ((((a) & 0x8) << 4) | (((a) & 0x4) << 2) \
                  | (((a) & 0x2) << 1) | (((a) & 0x1)))

const uint8_t LUT[16] = {
    EXPAND4( 0), EXPAND4( 1), EXPAND4( 2), EXPAND4( 3),
    EXPAND4( 4), EXPAND4( 5), EXPAND4( 6), EXPAND4( 7),
    EXPAND4( 8), EXPAND4( 9), EXPAND4(10), EXPAND4(11),
    EXPAND4(12), EXPAND4(13), EXPAND4(14), EXPAND4(15)
};

output = ((uint64_t)LUT[(x >> 28) & 0xF] << 56) | ((uint64_t)LUT[(x >> 24) & 0xF] << 48)
       | ((uint64_t)LUT[(x >> 20) & 0xF] << 40) | ((uint64_t)LUT[(x >> 16) & 0xF] << 32)
       | ((uint64_t)LUT[(x >> 12) & 0xF] << 24) | ((uint64_t)LUT[(x >>  8) & 0xF] << 16)
       | ((uint64_t)LUT[(x >>  4) & 0xF] <<  8) | ((uint64_t)LUT[(x >>  0) & 0xF] <<  0);
```

The size of the lookup table may be increased if necessary

---

On x86 with [BMI2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#Parallel_bit_deposit_and_extract) there's hardware support with [PDEP](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PDEP.html) instruction which can be accessed via the following intrinsic

```c
output = _pdep_u64(x, 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaULL);
```

---

Another solution on architectures without bit deposit/expand instruction but with fast multipliers

```c
uint64_t spaceOut8bits(uint8_t b)
{
    uint64_t MAGIC = 0x8040201008040201;
    uint64_t MASK  = 0x8080808080808080;
    uint64_t expand8bits = htobe64(((MAGIC*b) & MASK) >> 7);
    uint64_t spacedOutBits = expand8bits*0x41041 & 0xAA000000AA000000;
    return (spacedOutBits | (spacedOutBits << 24)) & 0xFFFF000000000000;
}

uint64_t spaceOut64bits(uint64_t x)
{
    return (spaceOut8bits(x >> 24) >>  0)
         | (spaceOut8bits(x >> 16) >> 16)
         | (spaceOut8bits(x >>  8) >> 32)
         | (spaceOut8bits(x >>  0) >> 48);
}
```

The way it works is like this

- The first step [expands the input bits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8461126/995714) from `abcdefgh` to ***a0000000 b0000000 c0000000 d0000000 e0000000 f0000000 g0000000 h0000000*** and store in `expand8bits`
- Then we move those spaced out bits close together by multiplying and masking in the next step. After that `spacedOutBits` will contain ***a0b0c0d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 e0f0g0h0 00000000 00000000 00000000***. We'll merge the two bytes in the result together

The magic number for bringing the bits closer is calculated like this

```c
  a0000000b0000000c0000000d0000000e0000000f0000000g0000000h0000000
×                                              1000001000001000001
  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  a0000000b0000000c0000000d0000000e0000000f0000000g0000000h0000000
  00b0000000c0000000d0000000e0000000f0000000g0000000h0000000
+ 0000c0000000d0000000e0000000f0000000g0000000h0000000
  000000d0000000e0000000f0000000g0000000h0000000
  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  a0b0c0d0b0c0d0e0c0d0e0f0d0e0f0g0e0f0g0h0f0g0h000g0h00000h0000000
& 1010101000000000000000000000000010101010000000000000000000000000
  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  a0b0c0d0000000000000000000000000e0f0g0h0000000000000000000000000
```

The output assembly can be seen [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIArKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFc8XaYDmlCBEzEBBk%2Bfly2mPZ5DDV1BAVhkdFxtrX1jVktCsM9wX3FA2UAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQmm24T%2BIIAdAhH2CYaAIK3d17BBABskgD6BPsRhB%2BYqgShnQEGegneX32qnm%2BwA9LD9hokcikXcLG4ACLYABiAHEABKPEwAdis932FKhh02GP2UFUhzMr0RqmxbOxKJhRzc3P2mzMXOJbjpEAZ5mZGlUKPZ2K5x15XFe8yOFkparhCLRmJROIJKMearFNLpYqZLLZKKRFstguF9MZEqlGmt0o5yLlN022H2AA5lZtVfD9mikdqNDikXqNAbKUbaaKHebkW7ncn3YchSLTY7U1a03mNB7rvtJP7A5qNBYNG4NBjw6ncRp8dHybHqfHsyya93q72ezXbVnE5LNhpR%2BOx5OJ0WvfsBSqYxS4ybh6ofeuN5ut36M3aE%2BKWZIj8eT6fS9TPd6uGXF/tiJgCCsGFCF/cSRiiW%2BzJssDQQvtsAADWUO5QgxSQICYGEoCgKDVx3bleXPEk90grkzUlZD5WOOcuViHlW3VIj1RQkU0NXAVqR5HDr13Mi4IPSVr3mZU33uNAGAmfYwQIH1IQCOQABUTFiCxFRE2kjkk0lbyAkCwIgxFFgA4DQPAiB9mvUgVPk9TcO0uS1MUzZFlk1SFI00sDPMvTYmUwyLP2JVrN0xTiVMwidKMjS/Rc7z9gATnsmyIK4Qs/IsrgtLM1yIC4AUIvUrgTMS0KrK8yK7KJYkPwDT8nheCFvl%2BAh/kBYEPgEwTQUKz5vmhbKyTuNV70fYhnygHiivmKqRIsfcvWLMwEIw1kJKo3lYiVOjOtqr4eqEvqBsvOdkNG7FxsQnDJD9W8SMzWbwTqhbhNE5ahsLVcNtiSTsOFSRLtIw63mO3qzqNFbFXQx1rtu6jhX5VjmuImaaqO%2Ba3v6j7i3i77zU2u7VsHZ7ush87Z19OHJV%2BiaaKVPa1SesGXohxb3ovYsSyxsabtx4VMdBrrXrJqGKYxx71oR/6KULV8HjfHL8qZyEFCBNYAHkvF4kqFGJvjiqBkkmrVJgpdQfYAFk7lxABJYUpJZH0NAeswNDCjQjZNs25ACAI%2BZVtXNbuIQAGkKQNyUja9i2fe9o2bbtvLPOF74ASBBh0B9GX232D4PgiZ5aEcBh44UAB3JgEneGCtd1twACoIjhrXXZnb13PtykQ/2UWmDWdBJYICxCAUGOw%2BBKOW/zzCwskLhVzuO5LXuIfLUrilWqfOla/rxvm4IVunpnzAG6l%2BfF8RsxS2pmVh%2BHvn3yFubvmXxv3hl4miqhRWZM8yf2unsXMEbzuF/R70t7lbmdqBkGZtPqWr9ZbQ1nF9OmfJ5yeX2naAB0sW7vwpAhRGX0CaUiXk/F%2BF8QHeiUuApSB9BZsTuBwRYtBOCxF4H4DgWhSCoE4DySw1ga7LFWJgRkmweCkAIJoEhiwADWIBTbnC4D6YaPpiRIi4AFWI0jjb6E4JIShPDaGcF4AoEAGguE8MWHAWAMBEAoFQCwBIdBojkEoGgYxpiYh1BYFFU2fA6AEGiOoiAERlG/GYMQAAnpwThli2CCHFgwWgvjqG8CwCwQwwBxDhNIPge8VQABumB1FxIBJUKW6xOEvDaMo2geAIjEDqN4jwWBlEEGIHgFg2i%2BAGGAAoAAangTAadxYJEYH43g/BBAiDEOwKQMhBCKBUOoOJuhNj6GiSgaw1h9CFPUZARYqAEgdDSQAWnFpsfY6yqApOIBEZImB1lMAUCwNRbRKgdBcBHUYzRSCBGmEUEo2RkipAEHc15uQ0i9GeXMVo7RqiTE%2BeMS5VQBBdHqL8/opQhjdBBXCqFTyYUSEWAoFhaw9CVMwNkkh8iOAUNIFQmhdCOB3AAEoa32MAZAyBNJcHOGYOkBSGBeGhHSBhVhLAGXwEQYg7CWj7A8FY%2Bg/KtgmV4Nw8JOikCWJMaK8xEA5XWJAMAexjik4uMoO4uJniSldNIAExgBBgmhOUZE6JsSaEJKuXgFJaSaEZOQFkg1uSyFxIKUUkpZT1g0MqdU2pVB6lNJaW0jpVDOE9OEKIcQgyo0jLUMo3Q8QDBGBmYw7lnrFkQGWastIGytk7L2dEQ5SgTlnIuYC5wEBXAguJA8iO0LZgxFeIkN5HQ61tu%2BfkZFzaQCtoqOCzowLPBNAkPWwdHRIVTEKCigdI7MjNAnZMJtLznLopWJilo2LcWkPIUouJpK1yvHWe8altL6WMo5bM7lAFeUkAFdpYV8rojsLspK2pEBZVGJfWQCgSqf0qoSAkZA7xgABQ1c44gridU0L1T4g1RqgkhLCdazAUSjBWoiXgRJjh7XKKdS67gvA3X5MKcUnxPqKlVJqdKupTAGnNNae0zpxGhnRv6RIaQ8alCJvGSAaQqbjA3psFm%2BAua1mcE2ds3Z%2BzS3HNOecgFtrq21tHWMBt6BV3/JyO89I6n7m6Y6Np2Fk6gXwoM3oMzEKV29peeMBdY6HPdBM6ipYm6BlcPvLu/FhLiW8FJUkNO0Qz13EEslc4Gg6Q0uQEFa9GabB3sIA%2BrYgrn3WPYaWD90r%2BEgHXOcCRZtpGyM2DIre%2BLFGkBqbETR/mVEcDUYIrRdHdEGOVQq/97WBh4FpSIyDWq3EeOCPqtjSGTUofNehy1vrsO4btakgjqhMnONdYIPJHryPeowDNrzAa6NBoYyG5j4aDVRr6bG7jsgE1jJoboMwUy02mAS/MiI2aJP5qk1sytKm/A1tuZZlojzZ19paEZtICKwc9uB/Z5TQ7p0Ius8Olzdn/kTAs4uqztnodzDRRizzO6ul7oJQeklnBj2nskPsHrdKRGRci/FrliXcDJbFd%2BNLgHRXsIFNlrQMrDEirMZ1jnAxiBJPeOs3Y0Tkpm369B7VQ2vFhP8UYwJ42zVxItZhnbNrkkLfSUt51K22OkY216yj23qN7d5/RxjoaWMRu6bIc7AzLvDN4zdnQeghPpsZy9t7tC80CALZsb7Q6bnuAB5p1zoP23g8j5Dhg0fYdTscxpxH06k9o5GJHrPM6Zj2dxx5rF3nCe%2BZJwFzg5KdZCDcOsxpd4xeSBpfsSXRhNKbDp/3CAnK5lJb5Y%2BoVwvWccPmDz3hpAECYCYFgGIOaKu8Gq7V5RpLGvbu0bl4kAVzg%2Bi4MSexAUAqWw0CmzgIeiXL9Uc13nROzDl/q2PlipB9kpGcJIIAA%3D). You can change the compiler to see how it's done on various architectures

There's also an alternative way on the [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#Interleave64bitOps) page

```c
z = ((x * 0x0101010101010101ULL & 0x8040201008040201ULL) * 
     0x0102040810204081ULL >> 49) & 0x5555 |
    ((y * 0x0101010101010101ULL & 0x8040201008040201ULL) * 
     0x0102040810204081ULL >> 48) & 0xAAAA;
```

More solutions can be found in [Portable efficient alternative to PDEP without using BMI2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38938911/995714)

Related: [How to do bit striping on pixel data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36256537/995714)

As you can see, without the availability of a bit deposit instruction it'll be quite complex in terms of operations. If you do a not of bit striping like this then it'll be better to do in parallel using SIMD

Comment: So, except for the hardware instruction, all of these options seem quite slow in terms of number of instructions (even allowing for compiler optimizations).

Comment: I know it'll be slow because it needs a lot of shifting, just like the portable compress right solution. Did you try with a 16-bit or 22-bit lookup table?

Comment: Sorry for not answering. No, I didn't, because LUT are effectively irrelevant on architectures without very good cache; and on x86_64 you gave me the PDEP suggestion. I +1'ed you though. ... by the way, does PDEP have a SIMDized version?

Comment: LUT method is still fast if you need a lot of bitwise operations in each step, regardless of the existence of cache. Unfortunately there's no vectorized version of PDEP. See [PDEP/PEXT operations for AVX](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/370419)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method combining initial shifts and selective addition:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t expand_32_64(uint64_t x) {
    x = ((x &       0xFFFF0000) << 16) | (x &       0x0000FFFF);
    x = ((x &   0xFF000000FF00) <<  8) | (x &   0x00FF000000FF);
    x = ((x & 0xF000F000F000F0) <<  4) | (x & 0x0F000F000F000F);
    x += x & 0x0808080808080808;
    x += x & 0x1414141414141414;
    x += x & 0x2A2A2A2A2A2A2A2A;
    return x + x;  /* remove the last addition for expand_32_63 */
}
```

Comment: Why is this better than any of the solutions in @phuclv's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47695658/1593077)?

Comment: @einpoklum: I do not pretend it is better, it is an alternative approach using masked addition instead of combining 2 masked halves. This might generate fewer instructions on some architectures.

Answer (score -1):

This might not be the most efficient or elegant solution, but it's the easiest to understand IMO:

```c
for (int i = 31; i >=0; i--) {
    reg |= ((reg >> i) & 1) << 2*i;
    reg &= ~(1 << i)
}
```

This will turn `00000000ABCDEFGH` into `0A0B0C0D0E0F0G0H` (Actually, that example is a 16-bit number, for which you would replace the `31` with `7`.  But you know what I mean)  If you want the zeroes on the right, `A0B0C0D0E0F0G0H0`, replace the `2*i` with `2*i+1`.

Comment: but the question is about a **fast** way to space out bits