# Fast way to rearrange bit into new byte

Tags: c, opencl

I have an array of two bytes with bits order like this:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
a0  b0  a1  b1  a2  b2  a3  b3  a4  b4  a5  b5  a6  b6  a7  b7
```

I want to transform them into new two bytes like this:
a0a1a2a3a4a5a6a7
b0b1b2b3b4b5b6b7

The intuitive way would be using a for loop for each bit.
Is there any faster way to do this ? Or can I use more specialized hardware like gpu and opencl to do this ?

I have 150 KB of these data each 20ms, and I would like to finish processing them in 20ms.

Comment: You only need one single loop, copying the `a` bit to the `a` variable, and the `b` bit to the `b` variable.

Comment: And unless you have millions of these "words" that you need to separate, or you have actually profiled to find this a top-two bottleneck in your program, I doubt you need to do anything else than a simple loop.

Comment: Copy what in the image to the question, [learn more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have 150 KB of these data each 20ms, and I would like to finish processing them in 20ms. I also don't want to get my CPU to too high % as I will use it for other things.

Comment: " Is there any faster way to do this ?" Faster than what? How exactly does your "loop" look?

Comment: use bit extract: [How to de-interleave bits (UnMortonizing?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3137266/995714), [How to replicate PEXT (parallel bit extract) with basic bitwise ops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48394866/995714), [Standard C++11 code equivalent to the PEXT Haswell instruction (and likely to be optimized by compiler)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21144237/995714), [Shift masked bits to the lsb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28282869/995714), [I want to pack the bits based on arbitrary mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41617369/995714)

Comment: [How to combine two 16bit-words into one 32bit-word bit by bit efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22101273/995714), [How to efficiently de-interleave bits (inverse Morton)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4909263/995714), [Best way to extract ODD digits from a binary number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30857819/995714)

Comment: @phuclv I see in the answers there is lookup table method, I think this is the fastest way as memory is not a problem for me. Thanks

Comment: @phuclv: A general question (how to deinterleave) should not be closed as a duplicate of a specialized question (how to deinterleave given all even bits are zero). Most of the links you give in your comments are not exact duplicates either. I added the one that is.